# Set slick slider value of JQuery according to width of browser

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slick.js

I am using slick

> kenwheeler.github.io/slick

```
 <div class="slick" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
</div>
```

I want to set the value of slidestoShow according to the width of browser. Any Idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2That's a classic responsive slider. Your slider initializer script should look like this:

```
$('.your-slider-class').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

and add your other settings to this script.
Next time just read the "how to use" on the link you gave, there's an example just like this

Comment: Thankyou so much dude. I read it very carefully in the link but dont know how I miss this.But any ways thank you for this